# #error 1107 when running a flash game on iPhone, using Adobe Air

Tags: iphone, ios, flash, air, adobe

I am currently trying to run a flash game on Android and iOS using Adobe Air.

While Air works nicely to run the app on Android, I experiment troubles with iOS. I am actually able to generate a .ipa package and install it to an iPhone (via iTunes). However, when I launch the application from the iPhone, nothing happens (black screen).

I then generated a debug .ipa which connects to a FDB debugger running on my computer, and the debugger shows the given fault when the app is launched:

```
#error 1107 the abc data is corrupt attempt to read out of bounds
```

Searching the internet didn't helped much. The issue is known (https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-14054) but this does not help in my case. Someone had the same error and fixed it by removing some 3D tween animation from his flash app (http://sierakowski.eu/list-of-tips/102-building-ios-app-with-adobe-air-things-learnt-when-developing-colorbyshape-app.html), but I doesn't use tween.

Any idea on how to fix this? Or a suggestion for an other way to port a flash game to iOS?

Notes: I tried on iPhone 3G and 4S and the result is the same. The game is coded via Haxe, which generates the .swf file. This main swf file uses other swf and xml files, which are present in the .ipa generated by Air.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen NME?

http://www.haxenme.org

If you are already using Haxe, it may be easy to publish for iOS using NME.

Personally, I have seen big improvements in performance using NME over AIR. For example, in Iain Lobb's BunnyMark benchmark, the iPhone 4 scored 16 FPS rendering 500 bunnies with rotation and alpha, using AIR. NME was able to render the same demo with 4750 bunnies at 30 FPS... a nine-fold increase.

It isn't magic but it's neat because it compiles directly to native C++, using OpenGL ES to render. It also works for Windows, Mac, Linux, Android, webOS, Flash (of course) and HTML5.

Is there anything in your application that is very Flash specific?

The big "gotcha" is that NME doesn't support SWF content natively, but there is a SWF library that gets pretty close, and runs in C++. It works great in Windows, but I need to test and make sure it works on iOS.